# Is Isaiah telling about the antichrist?

Tags: prophecy, revelation, isaiah, messiah

It is clear that Isaiah told about the Jesus, the Messiah, in verses Like Isaiah 9:6. But it seems to me that Isaiah made statements about a false prophet in 9:15: `...the prophets who teach lies are the tail.` And it states earlier that He(The Promised Son) will cut the head and the tail(false prophets).

One thing I noticed is that Isaiah says that there will be many liar prophets. It says like in the Apocalypse in Isaiah 9:16 that the false prophets will mislead the population . . .

> For the leaders of this people cause them to err; and they that are led of them are destroyed. [KJV]

. . .  but it doesn't make a big deal out of it. I mean in Apocalypse the antichrist is a scary, son of demon that wants all people to lose their salvation and we need to be carful NOT to think that he is the real Messiah. In Isaiah, the false prophets are just some liars that will mislead the population, but Jesus will end their lies before they can do any harm.

Answer (score 2):

***Context is everything.***  As you rightly point out, Isaiah 9:6-7 is a Messianic prophecy, speaking of the birth of the son who “will reign on David’s throne and over his kingdom”.  Note the prophecy about Jesus says his kingdom has a starting point in time and will last for ever - an eternal kingdom.

Then the subject changes and now Isaiah prophesies about the forthcoming anger of the Lord against Israel because His people have refused to repent and have not “sought the Lord Almighty.”  There was a very real fulfilment of this prophecy when the Assyrians attacked and eventually, Israel was taken off by its enemies into captivity.

You ask if this passage is about the antichrist, and if Isaiah 9:14-16 means the promised Messiah will cut off “the head and tail”.  A closer examination of these verses reveals that the elders and prominent men of Israel (the head) and the prophets of Israel who teach lies (the tail) will be judged prior to the coming of the Messiah.

There is no suggestion here that Isaiah is prophesying about end-times.  Verse 21 makes specific reference to the tribes of Manasseh and Ephraim, two prominent tribes in the northern kingdom who were descended from the two sons of Joseph.   Centuries earlier (Judges 12:4) they had fought each other.  Apparently, neither they nor the other tribes had either learned from the past, or repented and turned back to the Lord.  This is a recurring theme throughout the Old Testament.

Neither does this section in Isaiah’s prophecy relate to Genesis when God declared that the serpent would crush the seed of the woman in the heel (the crucifixion of Christ) but He would crush the serpent in the head.

Be aware that false prophets existed in Israel during Old Testament times, and also during the first century in New Testament times.  Indeed, false prophets are nothing new!  They continue to pervert the gospel – but they are not The Antichrist.  The Antichrist, who will be identified prior to the second coming of Christ, sets himself up as God, performing miracles and deceiving the world.

No, in order to identify who The Antichrist is (as opposed to the many antichrists that have already emerged since the death and resurrection of Christ Jesus), and the false prophet, we must turn to the Revelation of Christ Jesus as given to the Apostle John when he received visions of future, end-time events.  Note that these visions are symbolic, not literal.

Comment: But it says even in Genesis that Jesus will crush the head of the snake, so if it is a prophecy that Jesus will end Satan and antichrist, why does John warn us about him. It seems it is not human's business to care about antichrist. It is a "fight" between the Christ and the antichrist. If John warned us that means that we are Jesus's army in that "fight"?

Comment: Isaiah is not making a prophecy about end-times or the Antichrist. We have to wait till the first century before the apostles speak of the false prophets and antichrists. John was given a divine revelation to warn us of end-time events to ensure that the elect will not be fooled be either the false prophet or the Antichrist when he is finally revealed.  Yes, this is a spiritual battle, and Christ Jesus and his angels make war with the serpent and his seed and Satan is "crushed in the head". He, and all who follow him are utterly destroyed at the end of the age. We must stay spiritually awake.

Comment: All who follow Christ Jesus are involved in spiritual warfare and we equip ourselves with the armour of God to stand against the devil's schemes (Ephesians 6:10:18). John warned us not to be fooled by the miracles and wonders that the Antichrist will perform when he stands up in the last days. We will come under attack and that is why we must familiarise ourselves with the divine warnings given to John. We do not want to be caught out unawares! That's why we need to immerse ourselves in God's word. Then we won't be afraid because we know the outcome has already been secured.

Comment: But did Isaiah know about Jesus's birth and ministry?

Comment: But did John told about the antichrist, or some antichrists?

Comment: God used Isaiah to prophesy about the Christ, to point forward in time.  God used John  to prophesy about the events preceding the end-times before the return of Christ.  Even Abraham did not understand what was to happen, but he had faith in God's promises.  Isaiah did not understand what was to happen, but he had faith in God's promises.  John did not understand what was to happen, but he had faith in God's promises. Today, you and I may not understand what is to happen prior to the second coming of our Lord and Saviour, but we have faith in God's promises. The Antichrist is imminent.